# Fiz uma má avaliação por acidente, clicando no botão errado. É possível reverter?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-fechadas

Se eu aprovar uma edição por acidente, e encontrar um erro após aprovar, dá pra reverter?

Comment: Sim, podes reverter a edição na própria pergunta ou editar a pergunta novamente. Mas não dá para reverter a avaliação/revisão.

Comment: Ok, obrigado @JorgeB.